# How can I clear all options in selectize.js on the click of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a selectize.js function that allows a search ability through options. When a radio button is clicked, I want all the options in the selectize.js function to be removed so new options can be added to the selectpicker.

I have already tried `RemoveOptions()` and `RefreshOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

Your are able to do this inserting `$('#select').empty()` before populating the `$('#select').selectize()`.